# Hipernate won't update object, resets primary key to 0

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using JavaServer Pages, Hibernate and MySql.
I have an update page (form) for an object from the database, but when I try and update it I receive the following massage:

**Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1**

I've put some System.out.println functions to try and check where the error is and I've come to the conclusion that the primary key is reset to 0 when going in the ManagedBean, but only primary key value is reset, all other field values are the same.

Perhaps if would be useful to say that the primary key is mapped (with hibernate) as:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
```

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Comment: post code where you called update method, i think your entity object doesn't have the id set, and hibernate can't update a object without id, because he can't find it in db

Comment: did you do google on the problem, there are couple of discussions already on the SO.

Comment: Yes, BalusC, you are right. No id value is assigned to the entity and that was the problem. I've fixed it by adding another input text field for the id, and then pass that value to the update method.